# How to create chat based by laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add a chat function for my project, users can communicate between, what good extension package can recommend? Or give me a template reference，thankx!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Laravel-Talk](https://github.com/nahid/talk). Its so much easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Messenger](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger)

This package will allow you to add a full user messaging system into your Laravel application.

Comment: this package can use between 2 users?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.3 you can just use what's called "Laravel Echo".

More information in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting

And a free video covering Laravel Echo by the Laravel's creator Taylor Otwell - https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo

Comment: I am not familiar with packages, if that's what you are asking. However, upgrading to 5.3 should not take much time compared to what you will save by using Laravel Echo in my eyes. Plus, it is always a good idea to stay with the latest release of the framework. That's just my opinion, tho :)